# Making controls deployed in a NuGet package to show in Visual Studio Toolbox

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, windows-runtime, nuget, winrt-xaml

Someone [asked](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/discussions/434201) about getting the WinRT XAML Toolkit controls to show up in Visual Studio Toolbox. I can see that they do show up when I look at the sample project that uses the source code version of the WinRT XAML Toolkit and I can find them in Blend in an app project that uses NuGet-packaged version of the Toolkit - just by searching for the controls by name, but they don't automatically show up in VS Toolbox somehow. I saw in Tim Heuer's article that you can make them show up in the Toolbox if you do a VSIX deployment, but the Toolkit doesn't support that option right now.

Is it possible to get it to work with NuGet or are using the source code or building Extension SDK the only options?

Answer (score 0):

I think the possible way to do this would be to allow package manager to take additional parameters which would then add them to toolbox

If the default project templates reset the toolbox items each time, this might work great otherwise we will see versioning related issues in no time.

Comment: Hey, sorry for getting back to your answer so late. Can you elaborate on those additional parameters?